# Adding multiple users for same group in Camunda

Tags: authorization, camunda

In Camunda, I am trying to add Users to Authorization Object.

I am adding authorization object (user and groups) AuthorizationService as below:

```
for (Resource resource : Resources.values()) {
            AuthorizationEntity authorizationObject = new AuthorizationEntity(AUTH_TYPE_GRANT);
            authorizationObject.setGroupId(group);
            authorizationObject.setResource(resource);
            authorizationObject.setResourceId(ANY);
            authorizationObject.addPermission(ALL);
            authorizationService.saveAuthorization(authorizationObject);


}
```

I am getting the following error if I add the same userId for already added groupIds:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ACT_UNIQ_AUTH_GROUP) violated exception` :

ENGINE-03004 Exception while executing Database Operation 'INSERT AuthorizationEntity[90f11610-07c6-11eb-8aeb-025041000001]' with message '\r\n### Error flus
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to use the API as described in the JavaDoc:
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.14/

```
Authorization auth = authorizationService.createNewAuthorization(); 
//... configure auth
authorizationService.saveAuthorization(auth);
```

> The authorization object can be configured either for a user or a
> group:
>
> `auth.setUserId("john");    -OR-  auth.setGroupId("management");`
>
> and a resource:
>
> `auth.setResource("processDefinition");  auth.setResourceId("2313");`
>
> finally the permissions to access that resource can be assigned:
>
> `auth.addPermission(Permissions.READ);`
>
> and the authorization object is saved:
>
> `authorizationService.saveAuthorization(auth);`
>
> As a result, the given user or group will have permission to READ the
> referenced process definition.